# Sort by datetime, then group by date

Tags: sorting, extjs

I want to sort by a datetime value, and group by a date string.

I have found the [`sortProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.util.Grouper.html#cfg-sortProperty) on the grouper:

> You can set this configuration if you want the groups to be sorted on something other then the group string returned by the `groupFn`. This serves the same role as `property` on a normal `Ext.util.Sorter`.

So I tried the following, which only sorts the date correctly:

```
grouper:{
    sortProperty: 'StartDate',
    property: 'StartDateOnly',
    direction: 'ASC'
},
```

and I tried the following, which only sorts the time correctly:

```
grouper:{
    sortProperty: 'StartDate',
    property: 'StartDateOnly',
    direction: 'ASC'
},
sorters: [{
    property: 'StartDate',
    direction: 'ASC'
}]
```

You can try it here:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cei

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha support did not provide a full solution, but helped me a bit on my way. They found how to "fix" the problem at hand and told me to change the data type of the StartDateOnly column to `date`, but neither did this fix prove universal nor did it make any sense that this fixed the problem at all. But it showed some underlying correlations, which helped me to dig into the problem and find a universal solution.

I would say the issue is a bug in ExtJS, but I am awaiting confirmation from Sencha on this. I have to yet find the exact line where the bug is introduced.

Problem description:

When sortProperty is set on the grouper and at least one sorter is added on the store, the "transform" function of the grouper is set to the "transform" function of the first sorter (otherwise, it is null).

Solution:

You can manually override the `transform` function on the grouper by adding the correct sort type explicitly to the grouper config:

```
grouper:{
    sortProperty: 'StartDate',
    property: 'StartDateOnly',
    transform: Ext.data.SortTypes.asDate,
    direction: 'ASC'
},
```

Comment: Does your `transform` function only apply to the display, the sort or does it type the `string` variable in `date`?

Comment: @F0XS As far as I can tell from the ExtJS source code, the transform function on a sorter/grouper is only used by `sortFn`. It is explicitly to transform the value for sort (e.g. if upper/lowercase is to be ignored), but should not affect display at all.

Comment: If it doesn't type the variable, it's brilliant, your answer bypasses the bug in this case very well !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you make a sort on a `string` type but you have `date` by changing the code on your sencha fiddle like this :

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
launch : function() {
    var mdl = Ext.define('', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            /** @field {date} StartDate with format: Y-m-d H:i */
            name: 'StartDate',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i'
        },{
            name: 'StartDateOnly',
            type: 'date', // <= here before it was 'string'
            convert: function(v,rec) {
                return Ext.Date.format(rec.get('StartDate'), 'D d.m.Y');
            }
        }]
    });

...
```

Then you run, you can see that the group of date `StartDateOnly` is now order  by `ASC`.

After that, you can retrieve this data in `date` format and convert it into a `string`. 
But if you make a sort on a `string` you will always have the first of February last like now.
The problem is that it does an alphabetical sort on the days of the week. 
In order: Fri, Sat, Thu.

Comment: That's why I tell the grouper to sort by `StartDate`, not `StartDateOnly`. If I misunderstood the expected result of `sortProperty: 'StartDate',`, what use case exactly does the `sortProperty` have?

Comment: I tried a little bit thanks to your sencha fiddle, from what I could test, the sorting is done directly on the `property` it looks like it doesn't take accont to the `sortProperty` unless you change the type in `date`. I admit this is strange, I have been using ExtJS every day for a year and I have seen that some methods do not always give the desired result unfortunately. But I'm going to try more may be I can help

Comment: @Alexander I found another issue [here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?296819-Grid-grouper-with-sort-property-and-grid-sort-combined-bug). Apparently this bug is from ExtJs 5. Determining another `property` to sort via `sortProperty` will not work,
it could explain why it does not take into account your parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have submitted a bug report to sencha. Let's see what they have to say, especially regarding the unfixed bug from 2015.

Comment: Thanks to you too, thanks to your experience you could see that the bug still existed maybe it will be possible to change things this time.

Comment: I have added an answer that is loosely based on the reply from Sencha support.